# Adding a subreport to Active Reports

Tags: vb.net, subreport, activereports

I'm writing a report in VB .NET (using Active Reports) that displays details about a location, and then displays a bunch of images, which are stored in a database. The images are displayed in my main report via a subreport.

However, I can't get the images to load. I have two files, the main report (rptMain) and the image subreport (rptSubImages). The sub Detail1_Format in the rptSubImages never gets ran, which is why the images are not appearing, and I can't figure out why! I've included the code below... can anyone pinpoint why my subreport detail section isn't getting called? The rptSubImages report gets initialized, but if I put a stop point inside the detail sub, it never gets caught during debug.

Here is the code:

rptMain:

---

```
Imports DataDynamics.ActiveReports 
Imports DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document 
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class rptMain
    Private rpt As rptSubImages

    Private Sub rptMain_ReportStart(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart

    End Sub

    Private Sub Detail1_Format(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Detail1.Format
        Me.SubReport2.Report = rpt

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("rptMain")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LocationID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = locationID

        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

        Dim dsLocationInfo As DataSet = objPlugIn.GetProcDataset(cmd, Aquifer.PlugIn.DataFormat.Compressed)


        '--image
        Dim dtImage As DataTable = dsLocationInfo.Tables(1)
        If dtImage.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            rpt = New rptSubImages
            SubReport2.Report = rpt
            SubReport2.Report.DataSource = dtImage
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

rptSubImages:

---

```
Imports DataDynamics.ActiveReports 
Imports DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document 

Public Class rptSubImages 
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Detail1_Format(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Detail1.Format
        'some text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem :) I bumped the section that created and set values of the subreport out of Detail_Format and put it in ReportStart of rptMain, and voila, it loads :) I just had it in the wrong part of the main form!

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information on SubReports here:

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/09/how-to-control-sub-report-from-parent.html

Comment: That link is no good.  I believe it is now at [link](https://rishblogs.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/how-to-control-a-subreport-from-the-parent-report-in-activereports/).